# Best way to search and replace text from blocks

Tags: blocks

Is there a module or some other method to find and replace text from all existing blocks?  I've come accross [Search and Replace Scanner Module](http://drupal.org/project/scanner) but it looks like it only does search and replace on nodes.

Much Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to custom blocks, not those provided by modules? If so, the main data is in the `body` column of the `block_custom` table in MySQL.

You could use an SQL query to perform the replacement.

```
UPDATE `block_custom` SET `body` = replace(body,"findstring","replacestring");
```

---

Credit: [ChrisBrunner.com](http://www.chrisbrunner.com/2009/05/03/how-to-search-and-replace-with-sql/)